# ¿Como funcionan las listas en c#?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Me preguntaba si alguien me podría orientar o decirme cómo se llama el concepto para poder aprenderlo y/o aplicarlo por mi cuenta.

En ocasiones, usando Api's me he encontrado que algún méotodo devuelve una lista, por ejemplo en este caso.

```
 var ListaDevuelta = api.GetLeaguePositions(RiotSharp.Misc.Region.euw, api.GetSummonerByName(RiotSharp.Misc.Region.euw, Cargar[it+2]).Id);
```

Y esta lista tiene... ¿Propiedades? a las que accedo con `ListaDevuelta.First().Nombredepropiedad.`

Me gustaría entender qué hace `first()`, y como es posible que una lista tenga propiedades, cómo podría crear una lista que tuviese propiedades, ya que estaba interesada en crear una lista que guardarse nombres, emails, contraseñas, etc...

Quisiera saber cómo podría crear una lista con dichas propiedades, por ejemplo, una lista, con propiedad nombre, email etc y que traiga dichos datos.

`Ejemplo.First().Nombre`

Muchas gracias por toda ayuda brindada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito:

```
private class Idunno
{
    public List<string> nombre;

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Idunno> Lista = new List<Idunno>();
    Idunno objeto = new Idunno();

    string[] prueba = { "Raquel", "sofia", "Juan", "jorge" };

    for(int it = 0; it < prueba.Count(); it++)
    {
       objeto.nombre.Add(prueba[it]);
    }

    Lista.Add(objeto);

    Console.WriteLine(Lista.First().nombre);
}
```

¿Cómo podría rellenar dicho objeto con los nombres del array, y no unicamente con un solo dato?

Ultima edición:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que como lo declaras con var no es una lista sino un objeto y por eso puedes acceder con los los nombres de la propiedades eso es normal en el formato JSON Object y muchas apis devuelven json.

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Edito subiendo una foto, hasta dónde veo es una lista... (También te digo, que soy bastante nueva en la programación, asique quizá me esté equivocando, si me lo puedes confirmar te lo agradecería)

Comment: Exacto es una lista pero dentro de esa lista hay objetos y cuando dices nombreLista.First() estas entrando al primer contenido de la lista que contiene objetos entonces si llamas "nombreLista.First().nombreObjeto" entras al objeto almacenado en la lista

Comment: ¿Y cómo podría recrear una lista que contuviese objetos? (Lamento dar el coñazo, con que me digas que debería buscar en internet para encontrar esas cosas me sirve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te explico no es que la lista tenga esas propiedades, cuando usas `.First()` estas obteniendo el primer elemento de una lista, ese elemento es un `objeto` y ese `objeto` es el que tiene las propiedades.

Ahora para lo que entiendo que quieres hacer la mejor manera es crear una `List<Clase> listaObjetos = new List<Clase>();` a esa lista puedes guardarle objetos que sean de esa clase y acceder a las propiedades de los `objetos` guardados.

```
    private class Ejemplo
    {
        public int id;
        public string descripcion;
    }

    private void crearListaObjeto()
    {
        List<Ejemplo> listaObjetos = new List<Ejemplo>();
        Ejemplo objeto = new Ejemplo();
        objeto.id = 1;
        objeto.descripcion = "Prueba";
        listaObjetos.Add(objeto);
        int isId = listaObjetos.First().id;
        string isDescripcion = listaObjetos.First().descripcion;
    }
```

Para lo que requieres debes aplicar esto:

```
    private class Idunno
    {
        public string nombre;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Idunno> Lista = new List<Idunno>();
        string[] prueba = { "Raquel", "sofia", "Juan", "jorge" };
        foreach (string nom in prueba)
        {
            Idunno objeto = new Idunno();
            objeto.nombre = nom;
            Lista.Add(objeto);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Lista.First().nombre);
    }
```

En cada ciclo debes crear un `objeto` con su tipo de clase a ese objeto le asignas la información y lo guardas en la lista.

Este es un ejemplo de como inicializar una lista con objetos predefinidos, lo agrego porque algo me dice vas a necesitarlo:

```
    private class Idunno
    {
        public int id;
        public string nombre;

        public Idunno()
        {

        }

        public Idunno(int isId, string isNombre)
        {
            id = isId;
            nombre = isNombre;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Idunno> Lista = new List<Idunno>() {
            new Idunno(1, "Raquel"),
            new Idunno(2, "sofia"),
            new Idunno(3, "Juan"),
            new Idunno(4, "jorge")
        };
        Console.WriteLine(Lista.First().nombre);
    }
```

Comment: Disculpa que sea tan terca con esto, hasta dónde veo, el tipo de la lista es una clase, que posee objetos, y vale, sé crear clases (más o menos) pero, no con "objetos", o realmente no entiendo a que te refieres con ello. (Vuelvo a disculparme), Imaginemos una clase, y como cualquier clase tiene sus métodos y sus propiedades, ¿qué se entiende por objeto? hasta dónde sabía, era una variable que se transformaba en un objeto al instanciar la clase...

Comment: Vale, ahora con el ejemplo lo entiendo perfectamente! Muchisimas gracias... (no puedo hacer upvote), pero creo que si puedo marcarla como correcta. Gracias :)

Comment: Una clase es una plantilla para la creación de objetos de datos según un modelo predefinido. El objeto va a tener las propiedades definidas dentro de una clase, a cada objeto que creas le debes asignar una clase.

Comment: Exacto es la respuesta perfecta.

Comment: Disculpad las molestias otra vez, voy a editar y poner una porción de código, para ver si me podríais explicar como podría pasarle varios strings a la propiedad, y asi almacenar todos los datos en el objeto...

Comment: Ya te respondí amiga espero que te sirva, te explico en cada ciclo debes crear un objeto nuevo y a ese objeto asignarle la información que requieres luego de eso lo guardas en la lista y sigues con tus ciclos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias otra vez, @VictorPerdomo! =)

Comment: De nada, éxitos con tus proyectos. También te agregue un ejemplo de como crear una lista con objetos ya predefinidos, lo agregue porque creo que por ahí va la cosa de lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Me vas a perdonar otra vez, gracias por aportar lo último, siento que va a ser más liviano, he probado con los objetos predefinidos, pero al compilar me dice que la secuencia no contiene elementos. ``Datos.Where(x => x.NomnbreCuenta == "Jorge").First().PasswordCuenta`` , Sin embargo, de la otra forma si que me lo devuelve sin problema, ¿a qué se debe?

Comment: Es porque tu `"Jorge"` no es igual a `"jorge"` ahí esta el error. Un `string` esta comenzando en mayúscula y otro en minúscula.

Comment: No, no es por eso, (en el ejemplo es cierto que lo pongo en minuscula) sin embargo en estos momentos estoy cogiendo los datos desde un fichero, y en el fichero esta en mayúscula la primera, (como te dije, con el segundo ejemplo funcionaba) y ahora desconozco por qué :P @VictorPerdomo (te aporto unas imagenes)

Comment: El error lo tienes en que no estas guardando el objeto dentro de tu lista. `Datos.Add(new Datos (datos[0], datos[1], datos[2]));` mi recomendación no llames las `variables` igual que las `clases`. Lo digo por el nombre que le colocaste a tu lista.

Comment: @VictorPerdomo Perdona por estos errores tan básicos... ni me di cuenta, muchas gracias por toda la ayuda brindada, en serio, de corazón :P

Comment: Tranquila estas aprendiendo, sigue practicando y pronto verás que mejoraras. Recuerda la práctica hace al maestro y siempre hay cosas nuevas que aprender.